# How to display the contents of an html text field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Revised Question:
How can you display the text entered into an html text field in JavaScript?

https://jsfiddle.net/bjc7em1w/

```
<tr>
  <td id="number1"> (1)</td>  
  <td> <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="standardA1"> </td> 
  <td> <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="standardI1"> </td> 
  <td id="standard1">Describe the reason for the development of 
                     the plan and its annexes.</td>
   <td> <input type="text" id="comments1"> </td>     
</tr>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: When i click the run report button in that jsfiddle, I need it to display both the standard referenced from the html table, and the text field (comments) also in that html table. I got it to display the standard without the comments, but i Could not get it to display both. Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "referenced"? And what do you mean with "standard"?

Comment: PS. If you want to add information, please do *not* type it in the comments section. Please edit your question and add the information there, so others can also read it with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to add feedback messages related to your form. You can add an empty span tag to the section where you want the message to display and call it on blur.

For example, add something like:

```
<tr>
    <td id="number1"> (1)</td>  
    <td> <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="standardA1"> </td> 
    <td> <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="standardI1"> </td> 
    <td id="standard1">Describe the reason for the development of the 
                       plan and its annexes.</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="comments1" onblur="message()"> 
         <span class="message" id="message"></span>
    </td>     
</tr>
```

When the user leaves the section calling onblur, the message can be called like this:

```
function message() { 
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "message written here";
}
```

You can add functionality to determine when and how the message is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Since the discription of the problem was rather confusing to read, I will answer just the question:

```
var text = document.querySelector("#textbox").value;
alert("The textbox value is: " + text);
```

If you have any questions about this or want me to elaborate please say so.

Comment: I revised the question but you just answered it so Thanks.

Comment: Does this solve your question or do you need me to change it and explain more/ give a different example which is more relevant to your question?

Comment: It didnt directly answer my question but it led me down a rabbit hole which ended up solving my problem. Thanks.